# Avoid database duplicates when inserting new row

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i've a join table which I've create using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE user_group_join (

    user_group_join_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_join_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    group_join_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_join_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (group_join_id) REFERENCES user_group (group_id)

);
```

Then i've got another table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_flat(

    user_flat_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_flat_user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    user_flat_group_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    user_flat_location varchar(250) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (user_flat_user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_flat_group_id) REFERENCES user_group (group_id)

);
```

The user_join_group is to manage user permissions, now every time I update a flat for a specific user i need also to update the user_group_join table with some unique values so for example if i've got the following values:

```
user_join_id | group_join_id
          75 | 12
          75 | 13
          75 | 14
```

If i want to change the value 12 from group_join_id to 13 i should only have:

```
   user_join_id | group_join_id
              75 | 13
              75 | 14
```

I've tried to delete the row and then insert a new one but the problem is the following:

If i've got the user with id 75 having for example two flat in the group 13 and one flat in the group 14, if I change one of the two similar flats with the group with value 12 the database values will be:

```
user_join_id | group_join_id
          75 | 12
          75 | 14
```

when i actually would like to have it back:

```
user_join_id | group_join_id
          75 | 12
          75 | 13
          75 | 14
```

I hope is not confusing and someone can help me. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand that correctly, so correct me if I'm not.

If a user can have multiple flats of the same id, you should design your database as follows:

```
user_join_id | group_join_id | count
          75 | 12            | 1
          75 | 13            | 2
          75 | 14            | 1
```

Then, in your query, you just have to decrease the count variable or delete the row if it were decreased to 0.